# mark json field as a variable and fill it according to another json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

am trying to make JSON content dynamic and the idea is to have a simple json content

```
{
  "name": "@@var1@@"
  "lastname":"@@var2@@"
}
```

and have another json content

```
{
  "var1": "samy"
  "var2":"something"
}
```

the idea is to use the second JSON content to fill in the variables in the first JSON and become

```
{
  "name": "samy"
  "lastname":"something"
}
```

I did search for a library to help me achieve that and I did file `json-variables` but unfortunately, it doesn't work the way I want instead it does use variables from the same JSON file

```
const jv = require("json-variables");
var res = jVar({
  a: "some text %%_var1_%% more text %%_var2_%%",
  b: "something",
  var1: "value1",
  var2: "value2",
});
console.log("res = " + JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
// ==> {
//       a: 'some text value1 more text value2',
//       b: 'something',
//       var1: 'value1',
//       var2: 'value2'
//     }
```

Comment: You can combine the two objects before feeding them into the library. `{ ...obj1, ...obj2 }` merges two into one.

Comment: @ChrisG but i don't want to combine them coz i don't need the second JSON i need only the values

Comment: Sure, but it might not matter. If an object has additional keys you don't use, it only uses up a bit of RAM or traffic, so depending on the situation it likely doesn't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = {
  "name": "@@var1@@",
  "lastname":"@@var2@@"
}
const arr2 = {
  "var1": "samy",
  "var2":"something"
}
function myFunction(arr1, arr2) {
  return Object.entries(arr1).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = arr2[value.replace(/@/g, '')];
    return acc;
  }
  , {})
}
console.log(myFunction(arr1, arr2));
```